# Time delayed redirect with redirect code 301

Tags: apache, redirect

After reading some threads don't really got a solution:
For time delayed redirect is usually recommended an meta refresh redirect, where one is able to specify a time gap, after which the redirect fires. But no single word about, how to make such redirect with the redirect code 301.

Finally i need the following procedure:

- user comes to site,
- sees a message (html or an alert),
- **has time to read it** (some seconds),
- is redirected to another url,
- **the redirect code must be 301**

Bold are 100% needed requirements.

I'm on Apache (mod_rewrite on, httpd.conf or htaccess in use)

Answer (score 1):

even posted the question - promptly got an answer, as often.

**Solution**:

```
<?php 
$delay = 5; //seconds 
sleep($delay); 
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently'); 
header("Location: http://www.example.com"); 
?>
```